# liveusb multiboot ubuntu (x86 & x86_64) and freebsd 7

Tags: usb, boot, usb-storage

Is it possible to create a bootable usb (liveusb) with multiboot.

I want to have a ubuntu 32-bit and freebsd 7 as live bootable. If it possible I want third os: ubuntu 64-bit Live.

How much space will it take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/

It's made just for that purpose.
While booting, you get an option to choose specific distribution.

You also asked about space issue:
each new OS will add size equal to it's image size.

Comment: cat it do a freebsd live?

Comment: no it can'tt, it is linux + windows_install_cd solution only.